# haproxy ssl ciphers

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy

This was my ssl cipher setting in haproxy which I picked up from a haproxy thread:

```
global 

ssl-default-bind-ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:  EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4


frontend www-https

    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /ssl/private/ssl.pem no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets
```

But it's not working with `curl` and I couldn't even browse my site on Opera due to SSL error. When I use `curl -v https://myownsite.com` it gives me `NSS -12886` ssl connection error. I have tried to set `-- ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_sha` argument but still not working. So I have changed the cipher setting in haproxy to

```
global 

    ssl-default-bind-ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
```

The new list is not as long as the old one, but is it still strong enough for security? Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Do you intentionally have a space in the cipher list? Or is that only present  here due to copy/paste issues?

Comment: https://cipherli.st/